# Li elements not accessible

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access color and size in the following:
[image]

This is the DOM

[image]

And here is my code. It only outputs color and size, without the values. Please help.

```
t.desc= e.querySelector(".n_ck_s_itemoption_list").textContent.replace(/\'/g, '');
console.log("Values",t.desc);
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT IS BLACK AND LARGE...Only getting the titles: color, size. Thanks.

Comment: so, what expected output?

Comment: Although it's a nice idea to ss tagview, it would be so much nicer if you put the real code of that

Comment: It is correct, you are selecting the textContent of your main div, but it hasn't any text

Comment: Expected output is Black and Large, bt I'm only getting color and size. @PieroAlberto What I'm I supposed to do?

Comment: go deeper in the dom, you have to go in the children of your main div (another div) and againin its children, looping over the ul and again looping here to find the li :)

Comment: Looks like these values are supplied dynamically, and your selector executes before values are injected.

Answer (score 2):

Edited after you gave me the url

navigate to your url: http://www.forever21.com/Checkout/Basket.aspx?br=f21

and put this in the console

```
var productDetails = function() {
  var itemTitle = document.querySelector(".s_itemname > h1").textContent

  var item = document.querySelectorAll("div.n_ck_s_itemoption_list")[1]

  var color = item.querySelector("div > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(2)").textContent

  var size = item.querySelector("div > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2)").textContent

  return {
    itemTitle: itemTitle,
    color: color,
    size: size
  }
}
```

then test it...

[image: nice hips]

To learn Javascript well, study the pages on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and write some real programs, like a game.

Comment: post the link to the web page

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Hey @zelcon5 , I have a problem capturing data of more than 1 item...could you help? Each time I have two or more items in the cart, it only fetches data for 1...help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values try this:

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".n_ck_s_itemoption_list > div  > ul li:last-child");
var text = '';
for(var item in nodes) {
  if (nodes.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    console.log(nodes[item].innerHTML);
    text += nodes[item].innerHTML + ', ';
  }
};

alert(text);
```

```html
<div class="n_ck_s_itemoption_list">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>color</li>
      <li>BLACK</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>size</li>
      <li>Large</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** This just got confused because the [website](http://www.forever21.com/Checkout/Basket.aspx?br=f21) you posted in @zelcon5 comment have two div elements with the same class... only one of them is set with `display: none`, anyway use this:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".n_ck_s_itemoption_list > div  > ul li:last-child");
var text = '';
for(var item in nodes) {
  if (nodes.hasOwnProperty(item) && nodes[item].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display !== "none") {
    alert(nodes[item].innerHTML);
    text += nodes[item].innerHTML + ', ';
  }
};

alert(text);
```

Comment: Thanks @byoigres ... Works but it comes along with html text...how can you exclude that and just have Black and Large?

Comment: I don't understand, if you run the snipped you get an alert box with the text `BLACK, Large, `, what do you need exactly?

Comment: I need Black and Large texts only. What I get is text from the inner html as well... how do I replace that and just extract the Black and Large? They appear as the last texts in the alert. This is what I get:

Comment: This is what I get:                                                                                                               .........there's more html text then ends like this
            <ul id="ulLineItemSize_21c68461-45e4-4e8e-9e26-6213c281c4b3">
                              </ul>
           </dd>
          </dl>
         , BLUE/WHITE, Large,

Comment: It's ok, I have sorted it out :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CarolKariuki if byoigres's amswer was helpful mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var uls=document.querySelector(".n_ck_s_itemoption_list").getElementsByTagName('ul');
uls[0].getElementsByTagName('li')[0].textContent //retun "color"
uls[0].getElementsByTagName('li')[1].textContent //retun "Black"
uls[1].getElementsByTagName('li')[0].textContent //retun "Size"
uls[1].getElementsByTagName('li')[1].textContent //retun "Large"
```

Comment: brings back undefined :(

Comment: please make sure div element  with class name  "n_ck_s_itemoption_list"  is exists  when above code being execute.